# Why did the author put "to" in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

I can't figure out why did the author put this word in this place in the sentence:

> One of the protesters, surnamed Chiu, told a press conference that he was a witness ***to*** and victim of police violence in that night.

Is it a typing error or does it have another meaning such that we can't ignore it?

---

As you said, 
it means I can exchange the clause into **witness of**, and the meaning of the sentence won't be changed, right?

eliminate **and victim of**, the sentence below makes sense now:

One of the protesters, surnamed Chiu, told a press conference that he was a witness to   police violence in that night.

appreciate your help :D

Comment: Have a look at a dictionary. You will find witness to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyse your sentence in terms of the relevant sense units; eliminate the irrelevant elements of the sentence; then look at how the sentence works when you subtract one of the relevant sense units:

> One of the protesters [...] told a press conference that he was a {**witness to**} {and} {**victim of**} police violence [...].

Hopefully, the answer to your question will then become clearer:

> **'Witness to'** [something] *and* **'witness of'** [something] are both idiomatic combinations that mean more or less the same thing, and would both work here.
>  **'Victim of'** is a combination that *requires* 'of' as the preposition which relates 'victim' to a perpetrator or victimizing force.

Comment: @sukihibiki - In response to the comment you posted in your question (which should really have been posted under my answer :), you could use the fact that both 'witness of' and 'victim of' take the same preposition to simplify the sentence by dropping the first 'of': "...told a press conference that he was [both] a **witness** and **victim of** police violence [in] that night". (The insertion of 'both' is optional, but I think that including it increases the rhetorical impact of the sentence.)